# Confidence intervals for ARIMA parameter estimates and unit roots

Tags: r, arima, unit-root

Given the following simulation, I estimate a correctly specified ARIMA model and obtain the point estimate and confidence interval for the MA parameter.

```
set.seed(324)
n <- 120
x <- w <- rnorm(n, 0, 25)
for (t in 2:n){
   x[t] <- w[t] + -0.90*w[t-1]
}
x <- cumsum(x)
x <- ts(x)
plot(x)
plot(diff(x))

summary(fit <- Arima(x,
           include.constant = F,
           order=c(0,1,1)))
lmtest::coeftest(fit)
round(confint(fit), 3)
plot(fit)
```

The estimate for the ma term is -0.949 and the confint line gives:

```
>   round(confint(fit), 3)
     2.5 % 97.5 %
ma1 -1.015 -0.884
```

Clearly, the lower bound of the CI is less than -1.  So, if I am assessing for violation of model assumptions then a conservative view is that the invertibility condition has been violated, but the reality is that my true model is a perfectly acceptable MA(1). What does one do in a situation like this? Should I reject the model?